# angularjs save list of item(student) in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need your help I am learning angularjs . I learned how to save 1 item to database, I want to go further and save more than 1 item but I could not find anything in internet about doing that with angularjs. is not possible to do it in angularjs ?? . to explain what im thinking of I added the code on plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/sF3mBOcDilhQDQKYqeE7?p=preview

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('multi', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.students = [{
        'firstname'  : $scope.user_name, 
        'lastname' : $scope.lastname,
        'bday':$scope.bday,
        'bplace':$scope.bplace,
        'sex':$scope.sex
     }];

$scope.addNewStudent = function() {
var newItemNo = $scope.students.length+1;
$scope.students.push({'id':'student'+newItemNo});
};

$scope.removeStudent = function() {
var lastItem = $scope.students.length-1;
$scope.students.splice(lastItem);
};

$scope.save = function() {
    $http.post('db.php?action=addStudent', 
       {
        'firstname'  : $scope.firstname, 
        'lastname' : $scope.lastname,
        'bday':$scope.bday,
        'bplace':$scope.bplace,
        'sex':$scope.sex

    });
};
});
```

so after filling the info of number of student I want to click the save button save all the student to my database. if it's possible can u help me with this issue. thanks

Comment: Simplest way would be to loop over $scope.students in your save function and send a post request for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem is that you use values from the `$scope` when you save, so you can't save multiple students at a time.

You should use the `$scope.students` array that you already have.

I modified your plunker a bit (only the javascript), this should work for your needs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/T8qM1YCKBFmZbknWZ2n2

I didn't change much, I mostly put the `$http.post` in a loop. I would normally recommend using a server route which handles multiple objects, but not knowing about your server, that is the best I can do to keep it simple and functional.

2 other remarks :

- you send the `student.sex` to the server, but it cannot be set in the form.
- you use `last` in the html form and `lastname` in the save function, you must choose either and use the one you chose in both places